# Site Settings gives me File Not Found

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am getting file not found error when I am going to site settings. I checked the ULS logs to find more detail nut just seeing this in logs

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint etc.. but no file name mentioned

need help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Could be something masterpage related.  Have you made such a change recently?

Answer (score 1):

I found out, It was rather a problem with my alternate access mapping in the central admin where I didn't change the URL to have "https" instead of "http"

Thanks for your help.